# Python multiple dataframe methods in single line

Tags: python

New to Python. Can anyone explain how multiple methods are put together in one single line of code and how do we write a class with such capability?
Here is the code snippet I got but I dont know exactly how/why it works.

**df = df.div(100).add(1.01).cumprod()**

Thanks

Comment: Also the term we use to describe this is **method chaining** so give that a google to get more info as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each intermediate method (`div` and `add`) returns a `pd.DataFrame`, that's why you can put them into a single line. You can also implement it in a custom class if you want:

```py
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def add(self, other):
        # Return a new instance of Calculator with the method result
        return Calculator(self.value + other)

    def subtract(self, other):
        return Calculator(self.value - other)

    def result(self):
        # Since this does not return the same instance, you can't
        # do something like Calculator(4).add(2).result().add(5)
        return self.value
```

Then you can call it like that:

```py
print(Calculator(5).add(10).subtract(3).result())
# Outputs 12
```

The above class has the advantage of being immutable (considering `self.value` is private).

However, you can also do a mutable approach:

```py
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def add(self, other):
        self.value += other

        # Return the same instance of Calculator you're acting on
        return self   

    def subtract(self, other):
        self.value -= other
        return self

    def result(self):
        return self.value
```

In the above, no new instance of the same class is created. Instead, all the calculations are done inside the calculator. You can call it the same way:

```
print(Calculator(5).add(10).subtract(3).result())
# Outputs 12
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot.